# How to format 1st row in MySQL output differently from all following rows in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query that is returning the results that I need correctly.  However, I want to clean up the output a bit for my specific use case. Specifically, I'd like to remove a column from the output so that it only appears the first time it's pulled from the database.  Here's a quick example of the type of output I'm getting:

```
Event A - workshop 1
Event A - workshop 2
Event A - workshop 3

Event B - workshop 1
Event B - workshop 3

Event C - workshop 2

Event D - workshop 1
Event D - workshop 2
etc
```

This is what I'd like instead:

```
Event A
workshop 1
workshop 2
workshop 3

Event B
workshop 1
workshop 3

Event C
workshop 2

Event D
workshop 1
workshop 2
```

So, basically, I just want to see the "Event A" title once, even though it's part of the record of workshops.

Here's the php code that I'm working with (in this case, "campaigntitle" is the column I only want to see once per group. "assettitle" would be shown in every row returned by the query)  :

```
<?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="detail-nd.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_assetslist['assetid']; ?>"> Details</a> <a href="assetupdate-nd.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_assetslist['assetid']; ?>">edit</a> delete</td>
      <td><?php echo $row_campaignassetjoin['campaigntitle']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_campaignassetjoin['assettitle']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_campaignassetjoin['assettype']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_campaignassetjoin = mysql_fetch_assoc($campaignassetjoin)); ?>
```

here's the pertinent mysql query in the document header:

```
mysql_select_db($database_campaignarchive, $campaignarchive);
$query_campaignassetjoin = "SELECT assets.*, campaign.* FROM campaign JOIN assets ON assets.campaignid=campaign.campaignid ORDER BY campaign.campaignid DESC";
$campaignassetjoin = mysql_query($query_campaignassetjoin, $campaignarchive) or die(mysql_error());
$row_campaignassetjoin = mysql_fetch_assoc($campaignassetjoin);
$totalRows_campaignassetjoin = mysql_num_rows($campaignassetjoin);
```

Comment: Reformat the code to some human-readable style please.

Comment: sorry, I didn't format it correctly to start. It looks better now, thanks!

Comment: so, use a different query for each event? Or setup a nested while loop so that each "Event" just shows up once?

Comment: I tried using a php isset to see if the 'campaigntitle' had been output already, but then it would need to re-evaluate each time for when a new value for 'campaigntitle' is output.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me make the requisite observation that you REALLY shouldn't be using the mysql_* functions. You should either be using PDO or mysqli_*

Here's what I would do:

**update** In order for this to work, your results must be sorted by the campaign title

```
<?php $lastCampaign = ''; ?>
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
    <tr>
         <td><a href="detail-nd.php?recordID=<?php echo $row['assetid']; ?>"> Details</a> <a href="assetupdate-nd.php?recordID=<?php echo $row['assetid']; ?>">edit</a> delete</td>
      <?php if($lastCampaign != $row['campaigntitle']): ?>
          <td><?php echo $row['campaigntitle']; ?></td>
      <?php else: ?>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <td><?php echo $row['assettitle']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['assettype']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $lastCampaign = $row['campaigntitle']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

*I haven't tested this, but you get the idea*

Comment: Yep, this is what I was suggesting. The only caveat is that it assumes your records are sorted by compaigntitle first then other fields later. Other wise you might get Event A 1, 2 Event B 1 Event A(again) 3, 4, 5...

Comment: thanks for your help, this looks promising, but I'm getting an error: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()…" Any pointers?

Comment: Well if you used it exactly as I entered it, then that's why. I used the variable $rows in the foreach, but it isn't actually defined. You would need to replace it with the array of your results - the output of mysql_fetch_assoc in your case (though you shouldn't be using this function)

Comment: Ok, I've tried re-running the script with the following code: "<?php foreach($row_campaignassetjoin as $row): ?>", where $row_campaignassetjoin is the output of mysql_fetch_assoc.  It runs, but output is a little confusing…I'm getting single character output in various rows, like "1" or "7" or "T" or "F", when I'd expect full text values from the rows in the MySQL output. Some rows in the output are blank as well, when I'd at least expect values on all columns (except in "campaigntitle" when values greater than row 1). If you have any tips as to where I could look for tips, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: edited the OP to show the mysql query code, which is hopefully what you would need to see where things are going awry.

Comment: I'm happy to continue to help you debug this. However, long discussions are frowned upon on these questions. If you will, please post all of the relevant code in a gist or pastebin, and we can continue this discussion there.

Comment: thanks, here's the code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/scJKQ00R @adear11 I appreciate your willingness to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common application where you need to group your output by a specific column. There are many ways of doing this. Since you are using PhP, the way to go around doing it is to first make sure that you retrieve the record sorted on "event." Then keep a variable called  $old_event and keep comparing it to the event just fetched. If it is different, then output the Event name and set $old_event to the newly fetched event. If not, output only other columns.

You can also use a select with a group by clause, but if you are going to code as explained above, you will not need that... A simple select sorted by event should do.